# How do I define constructor argument to take custom object with ninject?

Tags: c#, inversion-of-control, ninject

How do I pass an object to a constructor argument with Ninject? Assuming the object is register in the container.

Comment: Have a google for Ninject Context Preservation in case the limited detail you've given us is concealing a requirement for multi-level context. (Though I've just realised you're also the answerer so probably not, Doh!). Also there is if you do a WithParameter with a ConstructorArgument which has the `inherit` (something like that) parameter set to true`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Apparently you do not need to explicitly provide Ninject with constructor arguments if the dependent objects are defined in the container. This is unlike Castle.

Here's an example. IGitRepository depends on IGitAuthor and IGitRepositoryPath. Since the two dependents are bond in my container they are injected 'magically'. Ninject is smart enough to see that IGitRepository's constructor takes them. So I just bind IGitRepository and leave off the .withConstructorArgument(s).

```
 Bind<IGitRepository>().To<GitRepository>();
        Bind<IGitAuthor>().To<GitAuthor>()
            .WithConstructorArgument("author", ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["GitAuthor"])
            .WithConstructorArgument("email", ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["GitEmail"]);
        Bind<IGitRepositoryPath>().To<GitRepositoryPath>()
            .WithConstructorArgument("path",ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["GitServerUri"]);
```